# How to express "prefer in order"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Let say, I am a little boy and my mother had several fruits (orange, apple, banana,...) and she asked me which one which I like, but she was not sure if she could give me that fruit ( I don't know why :) )

Therefore, I need to make a list of what I like the most (e.g: banana),then apple,... and submit for her consideration.

How can I express that list ? Is it "I prefer(like) in order : banana/apple.orange" ? If not, what is decent expression ?

Comment: "In order of preference, I'd like..." or, more naturally, "I'd prefer..., if I can't have that, I'd like..., then finally..."

Comment: "Look, lady, I **said,** 'I want a banana' — and I want it *NOW!!!"*

Answer (score -2):

When you are speaking to your mother, you cannot speak as in strict prose or grammar, rather a statement in a document.  It should be simple.  I prefer banana over apple, which I would prefer over orange etc.